# iperf3 stop running after 300 sec with error - unable to send control message : Broken pipe

Tags: memory, bandwidth, iperf, iperf3

Please help me, I have a problem of IPerf3 stop running after 300 sec (5 mins), when I want to use Iperf3 for testing for at least 24 hours. The error said **iperf3: error - unable to send control message: Broken pipe**

I use IPerf3 version 3.9 on ubuntu of windows 10 wsl for client, and the server side is the public domain that I don't have access to. So I can only control the client side. The client is connect to WiFi from CPE that inserted 5G sim card, while the server is on another network but it is a public domain and has configured iperf3 enable on the port 5021.

The client code on my side is run as below.

```
iperf3 -c <IP address> -i 10 -t 1500
```

and get the result as

```
[  5] local 192.168.0.107 port 57764 connected to 203.185.137.212 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-60.00  sec  28.5 MBytes  3.99 Mbits/sec  338   10.8 KBytes       
[  5]  60.00-120.00 sec  27.9 MBytes  3.90 Mbits/sec  229   16.3 KBytes       
[  5] 120.00-180.00 sec  28.1 MBytes  3.92 Mbits/sec  255   14.9 KBytes       
[  5] 180.00-240.00 sec  27.9 MBytes  3.90 Mbits/sec  228   9.49 KBytes       
[  5] 240.00-300.00 sec  27.9 MBytes  3.90 Mbits/sec  225   16.3 KBytes       
[  5] 240.00-300.00 sec  27.9 MBytes  3.90 Mbits/sec  225   16.3 KBytes       
iperf3: error - unable to send control message: Broken pipe
```

and i try --debug and show result in excel in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLn2f.png) which is the snippet from 240 sec - 300 sec. And you can see that at 290-300 sec there is no tcpi_snd_cwnd sending, same with the error that said unable to send control message.

**What should I do to make the iperf3 not stop running?**

Please helps me, I have searched multiple places in the internet and don't encounter anyone that has experience the same issue. Thank you very much in advance.

**My current suspicious**

- from this [link](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/1069), they have mentioned in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77kBU.png) that broken pipe could be the reason from memory full. But I still don't know how to fix this issue.
- from this [link](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/discussions/1296) mentioned that run multiple UE streams to the iperf could case memory full or memory leakage.

**What I have tried so far**, which still have the same problem. The things I have tried can be irrelevant as I am so new to Iperf.

- change from computer to be Raspberry pi -> still get the same problem
- use -N (no delay), increase windows size (-w), change from -t to -n 1024M -l 32k
- try parallel stream

Answer (score 1):

See related [iperf3 discussion #1499](https://github.com/esnet/iperf/discussions/1499).  The issue is probably because the public domain server limits the connections to 300 seconds.